# How do I pass the current capabilities to individual tests

Tags: java, selenium, testng, selenium-grid

This may be as simple as getting a variable from another class. I am still learning Java and Selenium.

I would like the test run report (ExtentReports) to be able to report the browser at a @Test level (capabilities). Currently Grid runs the same tests on different browsers, and the report does not distinguish them.

Using Selenium Grid, I define my @Test's Capabilities (including browser) with @BeforeMethod. I do this in my BaseTest class.

```
public class BaseTest {
@BeforeMethod(alwaysRun = true)
@Parameters({ "platform", "browser", "version" })
public void setup(String platform, String browser, String version)
        throws MalformedURLException, InterruptedException {    
    RemoteWebDriver driver = null;      
    //important: Thread local!
    threadedDriver = new ThreadLocal<RemoteWebDriver>();
    DesiredCapabilities caps = new DesiredCapabilities();
    // Platforms
    if (platform.equalsIgnoreCase("windows"))
        caps.setPlatform(Platform.WINDOWS);
    if (platform.equalsIgnoreCase("XP"))
        caps.setPlatform(Platform.XP);
    if (platform.equalsIgnoreCase("WIN8"))
        caps.setPlatform(Platform.WIN8);
    if (platform.equalsIgnoreCase("WIN8_1"))
        caps.setPlatform(Platform.WIN8_1);
    if (platform.equalsIgnoreCase("ANY"))
        caps.setPlatform(Platform.ANY);
    if (platform.equalsIgnoreCase("MAC"))
        caps.setPlatform(Platform.MAC);
    if (platform.equalsIgnoreCase("Android"))
        caps.setPlatform(Platform.ANDROID);
    // Browsers
    if (browser.equalsIgnoreCase("Internet Explorer"))
        caps.setBrowserName("internet explorer");
    if (browser.equalsIgnoreCase("Firefox"))
        caps.setBrowserName("firefox");
    if (browser.equalsIgnoreCase("chrome"))
        caps.setBrowserName("chrome");
    if (browser.equalsIgnoreCase("MicrosoftEdge"))
        caps.setBrowserName("MicrosoftEdge");
    if (browser.equalsIgnoreCase("iPad"))
        caps.setBrowserName("ipad");
    if (browser.equalsIgnoreCase("iPhone"))
        caps.setBrowserName("iphone");
    if (browser.equalsIgnoreCase("Android"))
        caps.setBrowserName("android");
    // Version
    caps.setVersion(version);
    System.out.println(caps);
    System.out.println(browser);
    //Initialize driver with capabilities
    driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://localhost:4444/wd/hub"), caps);

    //this uses below methods to set above RemoteWebDriver to the getDriver()
    //method in a threaded instance.
    setWebDriver(driver);
    initialize();

}
}
```

So now I have a `browser` variable local to each threaded Grid test run. I need to get that variable into each @Test method. Here is my @Test in a separate class. At the beginning of the `try` statement I would like to print the `browser` variable **for the current threaded Grid test capabilities**

```
public class Workflow1 extends BaseTest {
@Test
public void Workflow1TestInvalidPolicyNumbers() throws InterruptedException {
    HomePage homePage = new HomePage(getDriver());
    ExtentTest testReporter = ComplexReportFactory.getTest();
    try {
System.out.println("This is the browser:" + ??(help here)??);
        loginMethod("TestUser","TestPassword");         
        homePage.setFindAPersonOrPolicySearchField("1234");
        homePage.clickSearchButton();
        testReporter.log(LogStatus.INFO, "Searched \"1234\"");
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        if (getDriver().getPageSource().contains("Policy numbers should be 7 or 10 digits long"))
            testReporter.log(LogStatus.PASS, "Policy numbers should be 7 or 10 digits long");
        else 
            testReporter.log(LogStatus.FAIL, "Results incorrect" + testReporter.addScreenCapture(ComplexReportFactory.CaptureScreen(getDriver())));

    } catch (Exception e) {
        testReporter.log(LogStatus.ERROR, "Exception found: " + e.getMessage()
                + testReporter.addScreenCapture(ComplexReportFactory.CaptureScreen(getDriver())));
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: If your code is messy enough that you feel the need to apologize for it, you should take the time to refine it down to a [mcve] that demonstrates your question.

Comment: Ok. Well since it fits the MCVE just fine, apology has been removed. Still in need of a more helpful answer though. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the browser information is passed into the BaseTest.java class in the setup() method.

You could store this data in a variable which would then be available to all dependant classes:

```
public class BaseTest {

protected String browser; // add a property to hold this value

@BeforeMethod(alwaysRun = true)
@Parameters({ "platform", "browser", "version" })
public void setup(String platform, String browser, String version)
        throws MalformedURLException, InterruptedException {   
    this.browser = browser; // store the given browser string
    RemoteWebDriver driver = null;      
    //important: Thread local!
    threadedDriver = new ThreadLocal<RemoteWebDriver>();
    DesiredCapabilities caps = new DesiredCapabilities();
    // Platforms
    if (platform.equalsIgnoreCase("windows"))
        caps.setPlatform(Platform.WINDOWS);
```

And then the BaseTest subclasses could reference it directly:

```
public class Workflow1 extends BaseTest {
@Test
public void Workflow1TestInvalidPolicyNumbers() throws InterruptedException {
    HomePage homePage = new HomePage(getDriver());
    ExtentTest testReporter = ComplexReportFactory.getTest();
    try {
    System.out.println("This is the browser:" + browser); // then retrieve it
```

Comment: Looks like this is working, and should list the correct ThreadLocal browser Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can also get the browser flavor name and a whole bunch of information by querying the RemoteWebDriver object itself to reveal the actual capabilities by invoking

```
getDriver().getCapabilities().getBrowserName()
```

This does away with the need to even have the browser flavor as a separate data member in the test class.

See [here](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/remote/RemoteWebDriver.html#getCapabilities--) for javadocs.